# How can i have a handler if one of these fields don't have values when user pressed post?

Tags: android

I have this fields where every field is important and I don't have an idea how to do this. Where I want it if I pressed post there will be a message that not all fields have values. Here is my code.

### InsertActivity

```
package com.example.kun.carkila;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class InsertActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText etCarModel,etCarType,etCapacity,etImageURL,etFuelType,etPlateNumber;
Button btnPost;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_insert);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    etCarModel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCarModel);
    etCarType = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCarType);
    etCapacity = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etCapacity);
    etImageURL = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etImageURL);
    etFuelType = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etFuelType);
    etPlateNumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etPlateNumber);
    btnPost = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPost);
    btnPost.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    HashMap postData = new HashMap();
    postData.put("txtCarModel",etCarModel.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtCarType",etCarType.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtCapacity",etCapacity.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtImage",etImageURL.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtFuelType",etFuelType.getText().toString());
    postData.put("txtPlateNumber",etPlateNumber.getText().toString());



    PostResponseAsyncTask taskPost = new PostResponseAsyncTask(InsertActivity.this, postData, new AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String s) {
            if(s.contains("New records created successfully")){
                Toast.makeText(InsertActivity.this, "Car Posted!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent in = new Intent(InsertActivity.this, ownerhome.class);
                startActivity(in);
            }else{

            }
        }
    });

    taskPost.execute("http://carkila.esy.es/insert.php");
}
}
```

Hope for a kind response and I wanted to learn in an easy way. Thank you guys.

Comment: If this is a learning tool, remember that `findViewById` may return `null`. Any operation on a null Object will generate an NPE (Null Pointer Exception). Then, after your `toString()` call, you can use the `yourString.isEmpty()` to validate if it has content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first if each field is empty:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    HashMap postData = new HashMap();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etCarModel.getText().toString())) {        
        Toast.makeText(this, "Car model is empty", LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return;
    }
    postData.put("txtCarModel",etCarModel.getText().toString());

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(etCarType.getText().toString())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Car type is empty", LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    postData.put("txtCarType",etCarType.getText().toString());

    //and so on

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before executing your asynctask you have to check is any EdiText feilds are empty or not. Like

```
TextUtils.isEmpty(etCarModel.getText().toString())
```

You have to check for each EditText In starting of OnClick method and if any editText is empty then show alert and do not execute your asynktask.

Comment: So, ill be putting this inside an if statement if i'm not mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an editText array so that you can use a for loop instead of writing it all over. For key name in Hashmap you can use id name of editText in a for loop

```
String str = editText[i].getResources().getResourceName(id);
str = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(":id/") + 4);
postData.put(str,editText[i].getText().toString());
```

This code will be in a for loop to put all the data.

and in similar way you can check where this strings are null or not.

```
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
if(editText[i].getText().toString().equals("")){
//Error alert
}
}
```

I think this will reduce a lot of LOC.

Answer (score 0):

Yours is a simple problem. I have, because I needed these checks a lot, created a couple of utility methods for this purpose. You may place them in any class that you want.

1. `safeGetText()` to get text from a `TextView`:

   ```
   public static String safeGetText(TextView textView, boolean isNullable)
   {
       String result = null;

       if(textView != null)
       {
           CharSequence text = textView.getText();
           if(text != null)
           {
               result = text.toString();
           }
       }

       if(result == null && !isNullable)
       {
           // This check is for situations where the text cannot be null.
           // Now, I find this utterly pointless, but what the hell.
           result = "";
       }

       return result;
   }
   ```
2. 'isStringNullOrEmpty()' to check for null/empty strings:

   ```
   public static boolean isStringNullOrEmpty(@Nullable String input)
   {
       if (input == null || input.length() <= 0)
       {
           return true;
       }
       else
       {
           return false;
       }

   }
   ```

Although these methods don't do anything magical, they helped me clean up the way I checked for `String`s in my `TextView`s.

When you need to check the input (possibly in `onClick()`), put up empty checks for each field like:

```
boolean isEmpty = isStringNullOrEmpty(safeGetText(field, true)); // true/false in arg2 doesn't matter here
```

You would need to apply this check for every field in your current implementation. You could make arrangements to iterate through all fields in a loop like this:

```
boolean areFieldsValid = true;    
for(TextView field : arrayOfAllFields)
{
    boolean isCurrentFieldValid = isStringNullOrEmpty(safeGetText(field, true));
    areFieldsValid &= isCurrentFieldValid;
}

// Here, the flag 'areFieldsValid' will only be true if all fields are valid
```

Let me know if this solves your purpose, and/or if you need more help.